# Can I stop HTML Tidy from reformatting scripts?

Tags: htmltidy

I use HTML tidy with gVim, to make XML more readable. By and large this works great, as it indents tags according to their nesting level. Lovely.

However, it destroys the indenting in `<script>` tags. So instead of legible, indented JavaScript, I get one line.

Is there any way to tell it to just ignore `<script>` tags altogether?